# Node/Express route not waiting for Redis server callback

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, redis

**What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the `res.json(...)` command is NOT sent until any open calls to the Redis `client.somecommand(..)`  have returned?**

The code below is throwing an error related to the `client.hmset(uname, { ... }` trying to set a response header after `res.json(...)` was called.  When I move the `return res.json()` commands to right after the end of the `client.exists(uname, function(err, reply) { ... }` conditional block, instead of their current locations inside the block, the `anonymous` `token` value is sent to the client app instead of the generated `token` value.  This indicates that the callbacks to the Redis server have not returned.

How do I change the code below so that the `res.json( ... )` commands cannot run until the Redis server callback has been returned?  Ideally, there would be some conditional to wait a certain period before sending an error message if the Redis server callback takes too long.

Redis is added to the `routes.js` file containing all the code below, by adding the following two lines to the top of the file:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
```

Here are the various calls to the Redis server in the code below:

```
client.exists(uname, function(err, reply) { ... }
client.hgetall(uname, function(err, object) { ... }
client.hmset(uname, { ... }
client.expire(uname, 10);
```

The complete code for the Node.js/Express.js API route is:

```
app.get('/user**', function(req, res) {
    console.log("You Hit The User Route TOP");
    request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: authServer + '/uaa/user', 
        json: true, 
        auth: {
            user: null,
            password: null,
            sendImmediately: true,
            bearer: bearerToken 
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if(error){
          console.log('ERROR with user request.');
          return res.sendStatus(500);  
        }
        else {
            var uname = '';var jwtUser = 'empty';var jwtJSON = { "token" : "anonymous" }
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            if(body['name']){ 
                uname = body['name'];console.log('uname is: ');console.log(uname);
                if(uname.length > 0) {
                    scopesLocal = body['oauth2Request'].scope.toString();
                    client.exists(uname, function(err, reply) {//Check to see if a Redis key for the user already exists
                        if (reply === 1) {//a redis key DOES exist
                            console.log('\"'+uname+'\" exists');
                            client.hgetall(uname, function(err, object) {//retrieve all the values in the hash/object that we just set
                            if(object) {
                                if(object["jwt"]) { 
                                    console.log('object[\"jwt\"] is: ');console.log(object["jwt"]); 
                                    jwtJSON = { "token" : object["jwt"] };
                                    console.log('jwtJSON is: ');console.log(jwtJSON);
                                    return res.json(jwtJSON);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        } else {//a redis key DOES NOT exist
                            console.log('\"'+uname+'\" doesn\'t exist');
                            jwtUser = generateJwt(uname, authoritiesLocal);
                            client.hmset(uname, {//store a hash/object
                                'AccessToken': body['details'].tokenValue,
                                'TokenType': body['details'].tokenType,
                                'Authenticated': body['authenticated'],
                                'Principal': body['principal'],
                                'Scopes': scopesLocal.toString(), 
                                'Authorities' : authoritiesLocal,
                                'jwt' : jwtUser
                            });
                            jwtJSON = { "token" : jwtUser };console.log('jwtJSON is: ');console.log(jwtJSON);
                            return res.json(jwtJSON);
                        }
                        client.expire(uname, 10);//set the key to expire in 10 seconds.  use this to manage session length
                    });//end of Redis conditional block
                    console.log('jwtJSON is: ');console.log(jwtJSON);
                } else { console.log('uname is empty!'); }
                return res.json(jwtJSON);
            }
        };
    });
    console.log("You Hit The User Route BOTTOM");
});
```

The error message in the `nodemon` terminal is:

```
_http_outgoing.js:346
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/user/nodejs_apps/oauth_seed_app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/user/nodejs_apps/oauth_seed_app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:247:10)
    at Command.callback (/home/user/nodejs_apps/oauth_seed_app/app/routes.js:112:44)
    at normal_reply (/home/user/nodejs_apps/oauth_seed_app/node_modules/redis/index.js:714:21)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/home/user/nodejs_apps/oauth_seed_app/node_modules/redis/index.js:816:9)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.Parser.returnReply (/home/user/nodejs_apps/oauth_seed_app/node_modules/redis/index.js:188:18)
    at JavascriptRedisParser.execute (/home/user/nodejs_apps/oauth_seed_app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:413:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/nodejs_apps/oauth_seed_app/node_modules/redis/index.js:267:27)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:534:20)
```

I read [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent) about the specific error message.  And I read [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849900/how-to-wait-for-function-to-finish-before-continuning-in-node-js) about how to wait for a callback.  I also read [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053484/nodejs-not-waiting-for-redis-query-to-complete-before-continuing-with-execution) about Redis callbacks to Node.  But I do not see how to apply the answers to either of those other postings to the Redis callback problem in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `return res.json(jwtJSON);` commands in the OP were NOT segregated into discrete `if...else` blocks.

The solution is:

```
if(something) {
    //populate jwtJSON with a real JWT
    return res.json(jwtJSON);
} else {
    return res.json(jwtJSON);//this leaves the anonymous value
}
```

Doing this segregation for every nested condition in the above code got rid of the problem.